# Problem while using django Prefetch object

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

In my django application I have three models that are

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    class TypeChoices(models.TextChoices):
        INDIAN = 'IN','Indian'
        CHINESE = 'CH','Chinese'
        ITALIAN = 'IT','Italian'
        GREEK = 'GR','Greek'
        MEXICAN = 'MX','Mexican'
        FASTFOOD = 'FF','Fast Food'
        OTHERS = 'OT','Other'


    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,validators=[validate_name])
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    date_opened = models.DateField()
    latitude = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(-90),MaxValueValidator(90)]
    )
    longitude = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(-180),MaxValueValidator(180)]
    )
    restaurant_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=TypeChoices.choices,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ratings')
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)]
    )



class Sale(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, related_name='sales')
    income = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to get total sales of all restaurant within a month which have five star rating

My view is like this

```
def index(request):
   month_ago = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=30)
   monthly_sales = Prefetch('sales',queryset=Sale.objects.filter(datetime__gte=month_ago))
   restaurant = Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related('ratings',monthly_sales).filter(ratings__rating=5).annotate(total=Sum('sales__income'))
   context = {'restaurants':restaurant}
   return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

Template I used is

```
{% for restaurant in restaurants %}
    <p>{{restaurant.name}} - {{restaurant.total}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem her is I'm getting sales before one month. I want only the sales within a month.

Comment: `ratings__rating=5` means a restaurant that contains *at least* one such rating, so that is not (per se) the "average" rating so to speak. Is this the intended effect?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Now I'm not considering the rating. I have problem with sales

Comment: well it has impact: even if you manage to do the filtering of the income right, it will make *two* `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, and that means that the two will act as a multiplier of each other. In other words, if there are three ratings with five, it will multiply the income with three.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have tried without considering rating. But still I'm getting wrong output

Answer (score 0):

[**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) does not take into account [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) at all. You thus need to filter in the aggregate:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

month_ago = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=30)
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.annotate(
    total=Sum('sales__income', filter=Q(sales__datetime__gte=month_ago))
)
```

or if you only want `Restaurant`s with at least on related `Sale`s object within the last month:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

month_ago = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=30)
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.filter(sales__datetime__gte=month_ago).annotate(
    total=Sum('sales__income')
)
```